# office js change DOM loaded in task pane

Tags: dom, office-js

I'm developing an office add-in using office-js (not using VSTO) and I want to access the DOM loaded in the task pane from the java script function-file used in the manifest extension points .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can access the DOM loaded in the task pane from your JavaScript function-file. Think of it as if you have two browser windows or tabs and you want to communicate between them. Since the windows don't have access to a reference for one another, postMessage isn't a good solution. [One option would be to use localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12514384/5476848), which triggers an event on all same-domain pages when it changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access the DOM loaded in the task pane from your JavaScript function-file. Think of it as if you have two browser windows or tabs and you want to communicate between them. One option would be to use the [postMessage() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to notify the task pane and include any information you'd like.

Edit: see my other answer: this solution isn't feasible since the window reference isn't available.

Comment: yes you are correct , but my main problem is how to get a reference to the task pane "window" as the message should be called like that 

taskPaneWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer])